# Reuse existing neural network (LeNet-5) in Keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network, conv-neural-network

I am new to tensorflow and Keras and I would like to create convolutional neural network for image recognition. I know that each problem is individual, but is there any recommendation for case, when I want to use any existing CNN architecture like LeNet-5?

LeNet-5 input is for 32x32 grayscale images. My images are 50x50 in rgb. Should I resize them and convert to grayscale? Is same image size important?

Also, LeNet-5 output is for 10 image categories, I have only 2 categories. Should I leave the number of neurons in the output layer 10 and "use only 2"? Or should there be only 2 neurons in the last layer? When I change count of neurons in last layer, should I change count of neurons in previous layer (Dense 84)?

```
model = keras.Sequential()
model.add(layers.Conv2D(6, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='relu', input_shape=(50,50,3))) # input_shape=(32,32,1)?
model.add(layers.AveragePooling2D())
model.add(layers.Conv2D(16, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.AveragePooling2D())
model.add(layers.Flatten())
model.add(layers.Dense(120, activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.Dense(84, activation='relu')) # 84 neurons?
model.add(layers.Dense(2, activation='softmax')) # 2 or 10 neurons?
```

Comment: Make your choice with Keras : https://keras.io/api/applications/

Comment: Make tour choice in Pytorch : https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/torchvision/models.html

Answer (score 2):

[Here](http://datahacker.rs/lenet-5-implementation-tensorflow-2-0/) you have an implementation of LeNet-5 in Tensorflow+Keras.
This is only an example there are many implementations you can find on the Internet.

Be careful to follow the architecture of the CNN, your architecture seem correct to me.

Be careful also about the filters size!